# Choose the bundle identifier for an iOS and Mac app

Tags: ios, macos, app-store, mac-app-store, cfbundleidentifier

Suppose that I have an app called **A**.

Bundle Identifiers must be unique across all Mac and iOS apps. This means that if I have the app **A** on the iOS App Store with the Bundle ID `com.mycompany.a`, I cannot create an app on the Mac App Store with the same Bundle ID `com.mycompany.a`.

Ok, said that, what is the best way to distinguish the Bundle IDs?

Some examples I can think of:

- `com.mycompany.a_ios`, `com.mycompany.a_mac`
- `com.mycompany.ios.a`, `com.mycompany.mac.a`

Are there others that come to mind? Which you used?

Comment: Rather an opinion than a question I'd say, but com.mycompany.application.platform is what I'd use.

Comment: You are right, my question is -in effect- a request for opinions. I'm sorry about that. However, I hope might be useful to other readers. If you want, consider answering the original question with your comment, and I will upvote it. Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Rather a request for an opinion than a question I'd say, but com.mycompany.application.platform is what I'd use.

The reason would be to make it more and more granular towards the end, seeing the platform as a sub component of the actual application.

Comment: This way seems best. To see why, consider what would happen in each schema if iOS or Mac subdivided into two platforms.

Answer (score 10):

Apple now allows you to use a single bundle ID for Mac and iOS apps through Universal Purchase:

> #### Universal Purchase for Mac Apps Now Available
>
> The macOS version of your app can now be included in a universal purchase, allowing customers to enjoy your app and in‑app purchases across iOS, iPadOS, macOS, watchOS, and tvOS by purchasing only once. Get started by using a single bundle ID for your apps in Xcode and setting up your app record for universal purchase in App Store Connect.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03232020b

---

> #### Offering Universal Purchase
>
> Upload your apps to the app record using a single bundle ID. While the bundle ID must match the bundle ID you enter in App Store Connect, the apps can have different version numbers and build strings.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/support/universal-purchase/